# Establishing WebSocket Connection within and for a JS API

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket

**Aim:** In order to provide a simple, easy-to-use JS library that communicates with a server I am trying to establish a WebSocket connection at the start of my API and define the library's functionality thereafter.

**Problem:** The issue is that my socket's readystate does not transition to 1 (ready) before the library is loaded and the user's script is run. Debugging this has confirmed this and I'm not sure how to ensure my WebSocket is established before proceeding with the user's script.

**What I have:**

```
(function(myObject) {

var socket = new WebSocket(url);

socket.emit = function() {
    //do some tasks and create a var "message"
    socket.send(message);
}

window.myObject = myObject.prototype = {
    doSomething: function() {
        socket.emit();  
    }
}

}(myObject = window.myObject || {}));
```

Above, I've defined a custom method (socket.emit()) on the socket object that, in turn, calls socket.send(). I do this to manipulate some data before sending it via socket.send(), reusing code that would otherwise be repeated.

Then I have some very basic html that includes this JS library and a simple script runs as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    myObject.doSomething();
});
```

The error I get is: "Failed to execute 'send' on 'Websocket': already in CONNECTING state."

The library successfully loads but the Websocket does not complete connection before the client script is run. How can I ensure my WebSocket is connected (readystate == 1) before the API finishes loading?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're running doSomething on document ready, but the connection isn't ready yet.  You should look into the events available for your connection (onOpen, onClose, onMessage, onError) and restructure your calls so the connection is ready to send a message.

Comment: Right, but ultimately I won't be the one writing the scripts that will call the library. I want to handle all of the socket business behind the scenes so the end user can simply make the call they want.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is buffer all messages in `socket.emit` as long as the socket is not connected and send them once you receive the `onOpen` callback.

While this will handle your current problem you will see that new ones will arise:
You might want to handle disconnects from your server and reconnects and therefore you might need to extend your library API anyhow to also expose connectionstate change events and force the library user to only send messages when connected.